# Rails 3 many-to-many query on includes or joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have three models User, Activity and ActivityRecord.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :gender, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

  has_many :activities 
  has_many :activity_records , :through=> :activities
end

class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :point, :title
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :activity_records
end

class ActivityRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :activity_id
    belongs_to :activity

    scope :today, lambda { where("DATE(#{'activity_records'}.created_at) = '#{Date.today.to_s(:db)}'")}
end
```

I would like to query all activities for a user together with the count for their respective activity records for today. For example, after querying and converting to json format, I would like to have something like below

```
[
   { 
      id: 23
      title: "jogging",
      point: "5",
      today_activity_records_count: 1,
   },
   { 
      id: 12
      title: "diet dinner",
      point: "2",
      today_activity_records_count: 0,
   },
]
```

Please kindly guide me how I can achieve that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure this is what you want, but I hope I can get you in the right track:

```
User.joins(:activity_record)
    .group(:activity_id) 
    .select("'user'.id, title, point, count('activity_records'.id) as today_activity_records_count")
```

Then try `.to_json` on that result.

A good way to test it (so you can see the `SQL` result) is in the [rails console](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html)

**Edit:**

Reading you question again I *think* you're looking for activities of a particular user, so:

```
Activity
    .joins(:activity_records, :user)
    .select("'activities'.id, title, point, COUNT('activity_records'.id) AS today_activity_records_count")
    .group("activities.id")
    .where(user_id: your_desired_user_id_here)
```

Comment: Hi, There are 4 activities in the database for user id 1. But when I run above, it doesn't show today_activity_records_count and only returns one activity as well. Might be because I only have one record in activity_records for activity 1. how can I get other activities without any entry in the activity_records table as well? Also why isn't today_activity_records_count is not showing? Thanks a lot.. :D

Comment: Hi.. Sorry.. today_activity_records_count is showing. But how can I also get activities without any record in activity records table as today_activity_records_count as 0.

Comment: Hm, try a left join: `joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN activity_records ON activity_records.id = activity.activity_record_id")` instead of the join I wrote

Comment: I am getting all activities now.. But it's strange. I am getting all today_activity_records_count as 0.. Maybe I have errors in some other parts.. Hmm..

Comment: Actually the SQL generated from the query makes sense.. `SELECT activities.id, activities.title, activities.point, COUNT(activity_records.id) AS today_activity_records_count FROM "activities" left outer join activity_records on activities.id= activity_records.id WHERE "activities"."user_id" = 1 GROUP BY activities.id`

Comment: I tried out in database console as well. It also shows 0 for all today_activity_records_count.. So sth is not right with the query.. but i can't seem to figure out the problem..

Comment: I got it.. Stupid of me! It should have been "left outer join activity_records.activity_id = activities.id" instead of "left outer join activity_records.id = activities.id". I have one more question. If i would like to only get the count of activities_records which are created only today in the above query instead of all records, where should i put "where("DATE(activity_records.created_at) = DATE(?)", Time.now)". Thanks a lot..

Comment: You can add it in the last where, like this `.where("user_id = ? and DATE(activity_records.created_at) = DATE(?)", your_desired_user_id_here, Time.now)`. Hope it helps, please, accept an answer if it did. Good luck!

Comment: Hi. It doesn't work as it only shows activities with records for today in activity_records table. I would like to get all activities even if they don't have record that is created today in the activity_records. If they don't have any record, I want the today_activity_records_count to be 0. Can it be done in a single query? The alternative that I can think of is to have two queries - first to retrieve all activities for a user and then another to retrieve all today records of those activities. Then I combine them before converting to json. I would prefer a single query though. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Plese try this:

```
@activities = Activity.select("activities.id,activities.title,activities.point, COUNT(activity_records.id) AS today_activity_records_count").joins(:activity_records, :user).where("DATE(activity_records.created_at) = (?)", Time.now).group("activities.id")
```

When you want to output json

```
@activities.to_json
```

Comment: Hi, When I run it in console, it shows `SELECT activities.id, activities.title, activities.point, COUNT(activity_records.id) AS today_activity_records_count FROM "activities" INNER JOIN "activity_records" ON "activity_records"."activity_id" = "activities"."id" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "activities"."user_id" GROUP BY activities.id
 => [#<Activity id: 1, title: "Lean lunch", point: 2>]`.. as such it doesn't return today_activity_records_count.. There are 4 activities in the database but it only returns one. Might be because I only have one record in activity_record for activity 1.

Comment: Sorry.. My mistake.. today_activity_records_count is showing.. but I can only see one activity with records in activity_records table. How can I also get activities without any record in activity_records table as today_activity_records_count as 0? Thanks a lot.. :D

Comment: @activities = Activity.select("activities.id,activities.title,activities.point, COUNT(activity_records.id) AS today_activity_records_count").joins("LEFT JOIN activity_records ON activity_records.id = activity.activity_record_id").group("activities.id")
please try this.

Comment: Yup.. I got it.. Thanks a lot.. I have one more question. If i would like to only get the count of activities_records which are created only today in the above query instead of all records, where should i put "where("DATE(activity_records.created_at) = DATE(?)", Time.now)". Thanks a lot.

Comment: please try this "where("DATE(activity_records.created_at) = (?)", Time.now)". you are welcome..

Comment: Hi. It doesn't work as it only shows activities with records for today in activity_records table. I would like to get all activities even if they don't have record that is created today in the activity_records. If they don't have any record, I want the today_activity_records_count to be 0. Can it be done in a single query? The alternative that I can think of is to have two queries - first to retrieve all activities for a user and then another to retrieve all today records of those activities. Then I combine them before converting to json. I would prefer a single query though. Is it possible?